# HTML Tag is not using the 100% of width

Tags: css, html, sass, width

I have a project in laravel + Vue 2.0 + Sass and bulma.
Laravel uses blade template engine to render views and I'm injecting vue components into these views.
In one view of the project I can't use the 100% of the screen and I don't know why.

Screenshot:

[image]

In the right side, you can see that there is a white space.

I don't have styles for html and body tags. Im only styling the vue components and all is ok.
But I have this small space on the right side.

I tried to add:

```
html, body
  min-width: 100% !important
  min-height: 100% !important
```

but it's the same.

and **there is no margins and paddings to delete**.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Already checked the CSS 'position' property? Maybe setting it to something else than it's setted might help you (it did for me, but I honestly don't remember which one I tried).

Comment: Why are you trying to set the width to 100%? Its the default with for the body.

Comment: @KarulessWhisper Yes, but the problem is: If I set it in `fixed`, I lost the scroll. If I set it to `absolute`, another things like livechat bubble breaks. So, I'm trying to not use any of these positions.

Comment: @muecas Because I'm trying to force it to see if it uses 100% of the width. Without establishing this property does not work either

Comment: Do you use `{}` brackets in the real CSS?

Comment: You should post the entire relevant code.

Comment: @Banzay Yes. It's not the problem. I'm using sass and it's being mixed with webpack.

Comment: I'm using Vue 2.0 and sass

Comment: @muecas  I don't have styles for body and html tags. I only stilying the Vue components separately (and all of them are working fine). I added this code above because I'm trying to force to html and body to be 100% of the width, but I don't have relevant code for it.

Comment: If you want a body to fill 100% of screen you can use `100vh` for height and `100vw` for width

Comment: It's very weird. I solved it adding `overflow-y: scroll` in addition to the properties already mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird but I solved it adding `overflow-y: scroll` in addition to the properties already mentioned in the post:

```
html, body
  min-width: 100%
  min-height: 100%
  overflow-y: scroll
```